# Parse time string (ex "1h30min") in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing

Looking for a library/class/function/etc that will process various time syntaxes ("1:30", "1h30m", etc) into seconds/datetime/something.

I'm looking for users to string input length of time data should be valid for.

Essentially the opposite of momentjs's humanize: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/humanize/

Comment: http://momentjs.com/ does exactly this, plus more.

Comment: Or just write your own. It's not *that* hard and would prove to be a good exercise. :)

Comment: @RGraham I couldn't find examples of string processing, just adding durations.

Comment: @lc I could, but having something maintained with many supported formats seems a lot more useful than writing my own limited string processor

Comment: You'll want the http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/ methods, along with the `isValid` call

Answer (score 0):

This has some of that functionality.. Basic features, but is small and simple to use.

https://github.com/dpweb/time-ago/blob/master/README.md#tatimefriendlyx-period

```
var ta = require('./time-ago.js');  // node.js
var ta = timeago();                 // browser

ta.timefriendly('1 hour')  // convert to ms: seconds, minutes, hours, days, weeks, months, years 
 ==> 3600000
```